# Create a chrome extension which modifies a web page?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, edit

every time I go to a particular web page I hit F12 delete a node and uncheck a few absolute position boxes on two others. I would like to know how to do this with a chrome extension.

I have not made a chrome extension before so I thorough guide to making one would also be appreciated

Comment: You're looking for Google's extensive documentation.  Please ask a **specific** question.  What have you tried? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm trying to work out how to edit elements on a page with an extention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to read this guide first as Google suggests.
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html

Also, I think in order to implement what you want to do, you'll need to use page action.
So, take a look at this page about page action.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html

Comment: By the way, for your case, you can just make a simple bookmarklet. You don't need to build a Chrome extension.

Comment: I want to make the extension so that the page can be customised in various configurations for everyone to use, thanks for the tip!

Comment: oh I see. you can make an option page for users to set up their preferences.http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html

Comment: Also, you can preserve data by using chrome.storage.http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Comment: in order to modify DOM, you may use content scripts.http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html or you can use executeScript method. scripts.http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll go have a look at all this and see what I can make of it